# Closed as not constructive by wtf?

Tags: discussion

I would like to make a request to Stack Overflow's gatekeepers.

I am not very good at asking questions and most of the time I do not know the right questions to ask.

I find it helpful to read lots of different opinions, and to listen to lots of past experiences before making a decision based on various trade-offs.

To that extent I'd really like to see opinions about a particular library, server, API usage.

I find myself using and reading a lot of posts closed as "not constructive". While these posts might be subjective, they are **extremely** useful to me.

Can another version of Stack Overflow be created which allows opinions about particular technology i.e. Server Fault, Super User?

On a lighter note, it would be ironic if this post is marked as not constructive. :)

Comment: Also please link to the question in question. You can also look for a proposal on area 51.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that the "Not Constructive" close reason has been "retired"; it's no longer available. New, more specific and more granular reasons are now in place for people to use.

Comment: This is certainly on-topic here, so it won't get closed unless it's closed for being a duplicate (which I suspect it will be!)

Comment: If you're looking to create a new site in the network, then Area51 is where you should take it. http://area51.stackexchange.com. Then again, a site as you propose is at odds with what Stack Exchange tries to be, so I'd say it's very unlikely to succeed.

Answer (score 11):

You say:

> I really like to see opinions about particular library, server, api usage

Which is almost diametraically opposite to the kind of questions we want - see the [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) help page:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

And:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

---

You also say:

> While these posts might be subjective, They are **extremely** useful to me.

Well, the problem with such question is that they **are** subjective. That means there is no *correct* answer - you are getting opinions (or worse - a popularity contest).

Sure, having a bunch of opinions and options about certain libraries, servers and APIs can be interesting and useful, but that's one aspect of programming questions that Stack Overflow has decided to stay clear of.

Answer (score 2):

How about **Chat**? Chat was designed for getting opinions and asking questions that aren't on topic or are too specific for the normal site. The people on Super User chat will be happy to give you their opinion on some hardware or something, the people on Server Fault chat will tell you about server hardware, and on Stack Overflow chat we're happy to engage in holy war for over web frameworks for you enjoyment ;).